# Python: csv file and dictionary without Pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a simple problem...I have a file called data.csv with the following data:

```
enroll_code,student_id
10030,55000
10030,55804
10250,55804
10510,55000
```

What I am trying to do is to load the file, read the contents, and get the count of the number of values for each enroll_code.  Without using Pandas, how can this be done?  Here's what I have tried so far...

```
file = open('data.csv')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
next(csv_reader)
for key, value in csv_reader.items():
    print(key, len([item for item in csv_reader if item]))
```

Comment: Why are you doing `csv_reader.items()`?

Comment: just curious by why don't you want to use pandas?

Comment: @KillerToilet  more than one way to skin a cat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have issues in reading the CSV file correctly. Here is the snippet for reading CSV.

```
    In [8]: import csv
   ...: with open("data.csv", 'r') as file:
   ...:     csv_file = csv.DictReader(file)
   ...:     count = {}
   ...:     for row in csv_file:
   ...:         entry = dict(row)
   ...:         if entry['enroll_code'] in count:
   ...:             count[entry['enroll_code']] +=1
   ...:         else:
   ...:             count[entry['enroll_code']] = 1
   ...:     print(count)
   ...:
   ...:
   ...:
{'10030': 2, '10250': 1, '10510': 1}
```

Inside the for loop add your logic for counting all enrollments, which you can do it using a dictionary. All the best.

Comment: I don't know why, seems like he wanna try it without using any data science library.

Comment: @Frank for simple CSV file operation, developers don't want to use data science library. Even I would prefer the CSV library instead of NumPy, pandas if it is an operation like this.

Comment: Yes. I am using pandas in my project actually. I am just confused by this problem setting. :d

Answer (score 0):

Without using Pandas. How can this be done?

Say you are read the .csv like

```
0,1,1,2,3,
```

**Short Answer**

Numpy.

```
tmp = np.loadtxt(path, dtype=np.str, delimiter=",")
```

To get the length of the data. Just print the shape of tmp.

```
print(tmp.shape)
```

**To make it without using any libs.**

```
def csv_reader(datafile):
    data = []
    with open(datafile, "r") as f:
        header = f.readline().split(",")  # 获取表头
        counter = 0
        for line in f:
            data.append(line) # you can split the line later.
            fields = line.split(",")
            print("line: ",line, " ", fields)
            counter += 1

    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_reader("0.csv")
```

Comment: let's try it without using any data science library...

Comment: @RichardBroyles Updated. Check it out.

Comment: wasn't what I had hoped for...here's the output...
line:  10030,55000
   ['10030', '55000\n']
line:  10030,55804
   ['10030', '55804\n']
line:  10250,55804
   ['10250', '55804\n']
line:  10510,55000
   ['10510', '55000\n']

Looking for something like this....
10030: 2
10250: 1
10510: 1

Comment: @RichardBroyles hi, I am posting the idea here. you need to modify the parser according to the data format in your csv file.